# Add the ability to ignore sites on HNQ

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

Please add the ability to ignore sites on the HNQ.

There are some things I just don't want to see. Currently, there is a Q&A by one of the member sites  about masturbation on the HNQ, where one of the answers suggests self-harm as solution. I don't want that, I don't need that, and its not stuff I want to read, not when working, not in my free time.

I find the HNQ a great resource in my free time, but I would really like to have the ability to curate it so that I can exclude sites I find inappropriate or uninteresting.

Comment: To know what one of the answers was you must have visited it. So you were interested to some degree...

Comment: @Luuklag Yes, and then I realized that going forward, I wouldn't be interested in the site anymore in any way. You have to taste a dish before you can know you don' like the taste.